# My results are truncating into a single row. How do I get it to print everything?

Tags: python, pandas, flask, pyodbc

This is my code:
'

import pyodbc
    import pandas as pd
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def attendance_fetch():
    return render_template('Attendance_fetch.html')


@app.route('/Attendance', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def database_file():
    df = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':

        employee = request.form['employee_code']

        conn = pyodbc.connect(
            r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=file_location;')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select * from Employees where EmployeeCode =?', employee)

        for i in cursor.fetchall():
            employee_id = str(i[0])
            cursor.execute('select EmployeeID, AttendanceDate, InTime, OutTime, TotalDurationinHHMM'
                           ' from AttendanceLogs where EmployeeId=?', employee_id)
            columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
            print(columns)
            results = []
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
            for result in results:
                final = [result]
                df = pd.DataFrame(final)

            return render_template('Testrun2.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], 
            titles=df.columns.values)

        cursor.close()
        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

'

and then I wrote a html file to catch it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Attendance Table</title>
</head>
<body>

{% for table in tables %}
            {{titles[loop.index]}}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

[But the result is just a singular truncated column:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pqQd.jpg)
I would like for every row of result to be printed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is too general and vague, please read the [guide lines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on how to ask a good quesiton to increase your chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within:

```
 for result in results:
            final = [result]
            df = pd.DataFrame(final)
```

You are overwriting your df in every loop, containing one result. Place df outside the loop and try if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm a complete amateur and was struggling to understand what was going wrong. 'df = pd.DataFrame(results)' pretty much solved it.